# Domain of $(1-\frac{x}{x+y})+(\frac{x}{y})^{-1}(1-\frac{y}{x+y})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function
$$\left(1-\frac{x}{x+y}\right)+\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{-1}\left(1-{y\over x+y}\right)$$

I know that the domain is surely $x+y\neq 0 ; x\neq-y$, but I'm not sure which of these I should write. Which is preferable?

Comment: Yes, of course you should (sorry, i thought you were saying if you should write them both)

Comment: What to write I don't understand you

Comment: You should write them both

Comment: They are both the same thing: $$x+y\neq 0\iff x\neq y.$$ It doesn’t matter which one you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
1-{x\over x+y}+\left({x\over y}\right)^{-1} \left(1-{y\over x+y}\right)
= 1-{x\over x+y}+{y\over x} \left(1-{y\over x+y}\right),
$$
which indeed is undefined for $x+y=0 \Leftrightarrow x = -y$, but is also undefined for $x=0$. Hence, the domain is
$$
D = \left\{ \left. (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \right| x \ne 0 \text{ and } x \ne -y \right\}
$$
**UPDATE**
As pointed out in the comments by @Empy2, we also need $y \ne 0$ for the original expression to make sense. Even though $(2/0)^{-1}$ can be algebraically manipulated to $0/2=0$ but the original expression still does not make sense.

Comment: You also need $y/=0$ because x/y is part of the formula

Comment: @Empy2 updated, thank you